# angular material md-button not working on firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-material

I have some problem when I'm implement's md-button on angular material. On chrome href is working but on firefox not working. This is my code:

```
<md-button aria-label="signin" class="md-icon-button mdbtn120px">
  <a href="#/sign_in" class="btn-custom"><b>SIGN IN</b></a>
</md-button>
```

Comment: post your code using plunker /codepen

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<div class="md-button" aria-label="signin" class="md-icon-button mdbtn120px">
  <a href="#/sign_in" class="btn-custom"><b>SIGN IN</b></a>
</div>
```

It worked for me on a similar case.
I don't really know why this works though, might be nice to find someone who can explain the difference.

Comment: This works but it removes the animation from the button. You don´t have a fix for that?

Comment: I'm affraid I don't :( Maybe you should open a question about this specific problem, someone might have the answer and will find the question this way, since here I'm probably the only one notified